# How to see Ruby source code in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to open Ruby source code on my Windows machine but a black box appear for less than a second and then close without showing anything, I've tried to open it with  "command prompt with ruby" using File.open method but it keeps showing an error:

> File.open is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: You just need an editor to see the file content.

Comment: okay i can see the code now, thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally you can use every normal text editor, like notepad or ultra edit.
But the source can be encrypted, then you will see many bit's.

Comment: thank you :) i can see my code now

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use command `type`.

```
C:\> type ruby_program.rb
```

Just go into the directory, where your .rb file lives. And then do as above.

Read this [What is the Windows equivalent of the Unix command cat?](https://superuser.com/questions/434870/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-command-cat).